# Copy CronJob logs from /var/log/syslog to separate file

Tags: linux, logging, cron

I want to create a separate log file for my cron jobs.

Currently, I am using the following command to list the log of my cron jobs.

```
grep cron /var/log/syslog
```

How can I copy the output of the above command to another file so that I can get the separate file for my cron jobs logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could redirect the output using > like this

`grep cron /var/log/syslog > output.log`